# Best practices for mimicking user behavior in web apps

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know if there are any best practices or common patterns that are used when writing an application that mimics user interaction with other web apps.

I understand that Automated UI Testing do this sort of thing, so do applications that aggregate flight prices on travel websites.

Is there any pattern that helps with this. I will be writing an application in .NET so maybe there are some specific classes I could check out.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Note: I don't need specifically Automated Testing Suite.

What I am trying to achieve is log in to a web site, load couple of pages, do some calculations and based on that post updates on those web sites. I will be doing similar thing on numerous web site, so I'm trying to reuse existing tools if possible and don't want to start work with HttpRequest class.
I hope this provides clarification on my questions, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question is very generic. What things have you tried or thought of so far?

Comment: Are you sure you need an Automated UI testing suite? I usually just settle with Unit and Integration testing, cause I don't believe the pros outweigh the cons with UI testing. Most of the time you can handle the logic in your Logic layer, and just print the result on the screen (be it via data binding, or something else).

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities here.

If you want to scrape data from a website (aggregating flight prices for example), the code you write will communicate directly with the web server and will not usually simulate interaction with the UI. You [pull the data off the server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and use something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse and process it.

If you want to simulate interaction with the UI for testing purposes, you can use something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

It really depends what you are trying to achieve - whether it is testing an app or some sort of data mining.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to do data mining but also be able to log in as different users and post data. I apologize if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Have a look at [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). You can fully automate posting data and cookies as your web browser would.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) to automate most of the tests. You can use [Coded UI tests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/01/21/tutorial-how-to-create-a-coded-ui-test.aspx) that come with VS2010 if you don't want to write a lot. As @Andrew said - Selenium is good too.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to automate UI tests, I'm just explaining that UI testing applications do that. I'm looking for ways to do the same thing but for custom needs. I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

For web scraping in .NET, i've recently discovered [ScrapySharp](http://www.romcyber.com/post/2011/09/07/ScrapySharp.aspx). There seems to be little documentation and the author seems to be French. But overall it does the job for me, saving lots of boilerplate, and there is not that much to know to make use of that nice library.